# how to store multiple files in one file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, file, archive, file-format

How can I store multiple files in one file using python?
I mean my own file format not a zip or a rar.
For e.g I want to create an archive from a folder but with my own file format. ( like 'Files.HR' )
Or just storing files in one file without any dictionary or file format. ( 'Files' No file format )

Comment: How is this related to Python? What code have you written and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: I am writing a script for compressing a folder with my own File Format using python.
But, I have no idea about how can I make it.
Here's the Code:

Comment: The Code: [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vr67tz1c4kynfkl/Compressor.py/file)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use "tar" files.  In python, you can use the `tarfile` module to write files in the file and then later extract them back into real files.

You do not have to name the file `*.tar`.  You can name it something else related to your specific application, such as naming it `Files.HR`.

Please see [this nice tutorial](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tarfile-module) or read the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/archiving.html) to see how to use tarfile.